# Recursive function to expand json relations JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, recursion, expand

I'm a little stuck with this problem:

I have this JSON:

```
  [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sales",
        "superdepartment": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Engineering",
        "superdepartment": null
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Product",
        "superdepartment": null
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Design",
        "superdepartment": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Inbound Sales",
        "superdepartment": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Outbound Sales",
        "superdepartment": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Application Security",
        "superdepartment": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Front-End",
        "superdepartment": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Sales Development",
        "superdepartment": 6
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Product Management",
        "superdepartment": 3
    }
]
```

So, I need to expand the "superdepartment" relationships recursively according to the required level. Eg:

1. If I pass ?expand=superdeparment to my endpoint I need to Open 1 level of relationships
2. If I pass ?expand=superdepartment.superdepartment I need to open 2 levels, and this can keep going, so I think that I need a recursive solution.

Actually I have this code that fulfils the first level, but I have several problems replacing the nested objects to open a second relationship level.

departments.js --> Here I get the data (json) and call the "getRelations" method.

```js
module.exports.getAll = async function getAll(expand = null) {
    let response = await data;

    if (expand) {
        response = modelUtils.getRelations(response, expand, response);
    }

    return response;
}
```

modelUtils.js --> Here I wrote my core functions to fulfils the nested objects:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

//targetEntity is de JSON that I will use to get the nested entities from my actual ID.
// In this case is the same json, but can be another different.
module.exports.getRelations = function getRelations(entity, expand, targetEntity) {
    let tmpEntity = _.cloneDeep(entity);
    let path = expand.split('.');

    for (let i=0; i < entity.length; i++) {
        tmpEntity[i] = fillRelations(entity[i], path, targetEntity);
    }

    return tmpEntity;
}

function fillRelations(entity, path, targetEntity, level = 0) {
    let current = _.cloneDeep(entity);
    const currentPath = path[level];

    if (!current[currentPath]) {
        return current;
    }

    let value = targetEntity.filter(target => target.id === current[currentPath]);
    if (value.length > 0) {
        current[currentPath] = value[0];
    }

    level++;
    return fillRelations(current, path, targetEntity, level);
}
```

So actually with this code and passing ?expand=superdepartment.superdepartment to my endpoint I get this JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sales",
        "superdepartment": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Engineering",
        "superdepartment": null
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Product",
        "superdepartment": null
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Design",
        "superdepartment": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Product",
            "superdepartment": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Inbound Sales",
        "superdepartment": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sales",
            "superdepartment": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Outbound Sales",
        "superdepartment": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sales",
            "superdepartment": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Application Security",
        "superdepartment": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Engineering",
            "superdepartment": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Front-End",
        "superdepartment": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Engineering",
            "superdepartment": null
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Sales Development",
        "superdepartment": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Outbound Sales",
            "superdepartment": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Product Management",
        "superdepartment": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Product",
            "superdepartment": null
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see ID=9 element need to open the second level of nested relation for id=1, so It must look like this:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Sales Development",
    "superdepartment": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Outbound Sales",
        "superdepartment":  {
           "id": 1,
           "name": "Sales",
           "superdepartment": null
         }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how this might fit into the codebase above, but I think it solves the problem you're looking it:

```js
const expand = (field, lookups, xs) => 
  xs.map (x => x[field] == null ? x : {...x, [field]: lookups.find(({id}) => id == x[field])})
  
const expandAll = ([field, ...fields], lookups, xs) =>  
  field == undefined
    ? xs
  : fields .length > 0
    ? expandAll (fields, expand (field, lookups, xs), xs)
  : // else
    expand (field, lookups, xs)

const fillRelations = (expansionStr, xs) => 
  expandAll (expansionStr .split ('.'), xs, xs)

const departments = [{ id: 1, name: "Sales", superdepartment: null }, { id: 2, name: "Engineering", superdepartment: null }, { id: 3, name: "Product", superdepartment: null }, { id: 4, name: "Design", superdepartment: 3 }, { id: 5, name: "Inbound Sales", superdepartment: 1 }, { id: 6, name: "Outbound Sales", superdepartment: 1 }, { id: 7, name: "Application Security", superdepartment: 2 }, { id: 8, name: "Front-End", superdepartment: 2 }, { id: 9, name: "Sales Development", superdepartment: 6 }, { id: 10, name: "Product Management", superdepartment: 3}]

console .log (
  JSON.stringify (
    fillRelations ('superdepartment.superdepartment', departments)
  , null, 4)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We define `expand`, which takes a field name, an array of items already expanded and an array of items to look up, and updates the last list by looking up in the expanded list (`lookups`) the one which matches the given field.  We could use this like:

```js
expand('superdepartment', departments, departments)
```

Then we build on that with `expandAll`, which takes an array of field names and recursively calls itself and `expand` to fill in the details for the missing fields.  We could use this like:

```js
expandAll(['superdepartment', 'superdepartment'], departments, departments)
```

Finally, we give our public API in `fillRelations`, which kick-starts the process by splitting the input string into an array and passing our initial object in as both the lookup list and the items to expand.  This has the signature you want:

```js
fillRelations('superdepartment.superdepartment', departments)
```

We add the `JSON.stringify` call to skip the SO console's reference stringification.  But note that, for instance, the first result and the `superdepartement` property of the sixth result and the `superdeparment.superdepartment` property of the ninth result all refer to the same object.  I see you're doing some cloning in your code, and if you don't want these shared references, you could update `expand` to return *clone*s of your objects.

Comment: Thank you Scott, I quickly tested it and is working fine. It just needs some modifications to fit in my code but in general its working good!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a straightforward (and recursive) solution to your problem:

```js
const data = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sales",
        "superdepartment": null
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Engineering",
        "superdepartment": null
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Product",
        "superdepartment": null
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Design",
        "superdepartment": 3
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Inbound Sales",
        "superdepartment": 1
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Outbound Sales",
        "superdepartment": 1
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Application Security",
        "superdepartment": 2
    }, {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Front-End",
        "superdepartment": 2
    }, {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Sales Development",
        "superdepartment": 6
    }, {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Product Management",
        "superdepartment": 3
    }
];

function compute(data, expand) {
    const path = expand.split('.');
    return data.map(x => attachEntities(x, data, path));
}

function attachEntities(obj, data, [prop, ...props]) {
    return prop ? {
        ...obj,
        [prop]: obj[prop] && attachEntities(data.find(y => y.id === obj[prop]) || obj[prop], data, props)
    }
     : obj;
}

console.log('One level', compute(data, 'superdepartment'));
console.log('Two levels', compute(data, 'superdepartment.superdepartment'));
console.log('Three levels', compute(data, 'superdepartment.superdepartment.superdepartment'));
```

Comment: This is quite nice, simpler than mine and easy to follow.  One suggestion would be to destructure `path` either in the parameters or before the `return` into `[node, ...nodes]` or some such to avoid the repetition of `path[0]` everywhere.

Comment: Indeed I did what you suggested and it's much clearer, thanks